# Behat and laravel 5.5: Class hash does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, behat

I keep getting

```
In Container.php line 752:
  Class hash does not exist
```

When I run behat on a laravel 5.5 project

I have php 7.1, ubuntu 16.04 and  `"behat/behat": "^3.5",`.

My coworkers don't seem to have this problem, only me. A pc specific issue?

I tried `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan cache:clear`, nothing works

Comment: Laravel's `Hash` class has an uppercase H, which will matter on a case-sensitive filesystem like Linux/Mac. Find where you've done something like `hash::make` and change it to `Hash::make`.

Comment: @ceejayoz I dd a `ctrl + shift  + f` in vscode, meaning i searched all files for that string, found nothing

Comment: Try `php artisan config:clear`. If that doesn't work, delete `packages.php` in `bootstrap/cache`

Comment: @adam done all, nothing works, a question does one need to supply a path for beehat? because if I run it in laravel as shown above it does not work, but if I do `/vendor/bin/behat Tests` it works

Comment: Interesting. I did find the string `'hash'` in `bootstrap/cache/services.php`: `'hash' => 'Illuminate\\Hashing\\HashServiceProvider',`

Comment: @adam ah i was searching for `hash::make`

Comment: @adam The one in `services.php` should be lowercased.

Comment: @ceejayoz so no need to change that

Comment: @ceejayoz why not give behat a path? if you give it a path you get a different error, maybe something related to actual unit tests but at least not this one. Today is my first day using behat, just wondering if giving it a path the wrong thing to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I run the command below, everything runs smoothly and I see no errors, not sure if this is a fix or not.

`/vendor/bin/behat --tags=Ready`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience this kind of errors comes from wrong built caches.
You need to recreate your caches.
For first make sure that all your packages are ready to use:

> ```
> composer install
> composer dump-autoload
> ```

Now remove "packages.php", "services.php", "config.php" from "bootstrap/cache" and run:

> ```
> php artisan config:cache
> ```

This will generate new files in that directory. If you will get an error after running that command, then may you have something wrong somewhere in your "config/*.php" files. Find that, fix and run "config:cache" again

Answer (score 0):

Search the app folder for "use Hash;"

I found one calling that is not being used, i just removed it and the issue disappeared.